# change the key in the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to change the name of the key in the array.

I have something like:

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,$qry);
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
{
   $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"results":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```

Results can occur in three variations

1. `results: [{id_a:1, title:V}]`
2. `results: [{id_b:1, title:V}]`
3. `results: [{id_c:1, title:V}]`

My sql query is determining which of the variations will I receive, and therefore I need to check what is the key name and change it to `id` only.

So I need to check something like  `if('key'==id_a || 'key'==id_b || 'key'==id_c )` change the 'key' to `id`

Comment: Why not modify your database query to alias id_a as id, etc?

Comment: I forgot to wrote that I don't want to mess up with the query. Is there any way to replace the array key? I mean there must be way...

Comment: There is, but DB query aliasing would really be far easier

Comment: Suppose you have a query like: `SELECT id_a, title FROM table`. Couldn't you just simply do: `SELECT id_a AS id, title FROM table`?

Comment: why not? that would be the easiest and best solution.

Comment: If I change the query then I need to change almost 10 files which are set to work with that result sets. I agree that using ALIAS would be the easiest way but... I should think of this earlier but I haven't and that's my mistake and now the easiest way would be to change the key name.

Comment: For future editing and working with your code, i suggest you to think if it's better to do "a workaround" now, and make your code more complex, or just do little "rewrite", that will take you a bit of your time, but can make everything more clear and straight-forward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're disinclined to take the easy approach and modify the database query to use aliases:

```
$result=mysqli_query($link,$qry);
while($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) 
{
    if (isset($obj->id_a)) {
        $obj->id = $obj->id_a;
        unset($obj->id_a);
    } elseif (isset($obj->id_b)) {
        $obj->id = $obj->id_b;
        unset($obj->id_b);
    } elseif (isset($obj->id_c)) {
        $obj->id = $obj->id_c;
        unset($obj->id_c);
    }
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

echo '{"results":'.json_encode($arr).'}'
```

**EDIT**

```
$objects = array();
$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->id_a = 1;
$object1->title = "Title 1";
$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->id_b = 2;
$object2->title = "Title 2";
$objects[0] = $object1;
$objects[1] = $object2;


foreach($objects as $obj) {
    if (isset($obj->id_a)) {
        $obj->id = $obj->id_a;
        unset($obj->id_a);
    } elseif (isset($obj->id_b)) {
        $obj->id = $obj->id_b;
        unset($obj->id_b);
    } elseif (isset($obj->id_c)) {
        $obj->id = $obj->id_c;
        unset($obj->id_c);
    }

    var_dump($obj);
}
```

gives

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'title' => string 'Title 1' (length=7)
  public 'id' => int 1

object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'title' => string 'Title 2' (length=7)
  public 'id' => int 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$objects = array();
$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->id_a = 1;
$object1->label = "label1";
$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->id_b = 2;
$object2->label = "label2";
$objects[0] = $object1;
$objects[1] = $object2;

foreach($objects as $object) {
    foreach($object as $key => $value) {
        if(strpos($key, "id") !== false) {
            unset($object->$key);
            $key = "id";
            $object->$key = $value;
        }
    }
}
print_r($objects);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wan to change the name of key,

```
$i=0;
foreach(mysqli_fetch_object($result) as $key=>$value) {
        $arr[$key."_".$i] = $value;
        $i++;
}
echo '{"results":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
```